# Trouble adding multiple annotation pins in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

My application simply opens to a map view and a button. Each time the user hits the button, I'd like a pin to be dropped at the current location. The user's coordinates are sent to Firebase and then pulled back down, stored in an annotation, and then in an annotation array.

When the user moves to a new location and hits the button, I'd like for the old pin(s) to still be shown (during current launch). **Here's the trouble:** when I call `mapView.addAnnotations(annotationArray)`, I only see one pin (the most recent one), and lose the rest.

In `viewDidLoad`, I have the latitude and longitude observers set up to pull the Firebase data back down:

```
 ref = Database.database().reference()
 databaseHandle = ref?.child("Latitude").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.latitude = snapshot.value as? CLLocationDegrees
    })
    databaseHandle = ref?.child("Longitude").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.longitude = snapshot.value as? CLLocationDegrees
    })
```

Storing current location in `myLatitude` and `myLongitude` variables:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {

    myLatitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    myLongitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
}
```

When the button is pressed, user's current location coordinates are stored in firebase. They are pulled back down as the variables `pullLatitude` and `pullLongitude`:

```
@IBAction func tagLocationBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    if myLongitude != nil && myLatitude != nil {
        ref?.child("Latitude").childByAutoId().setValue(myLatitude!)
        ref?.child("Longitude").childByAutoId().setValue(myLongitude!)
    }

    if pullLatitude != nil && pullLongitude != nil {

        coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(pullLatitude!, pullLongitude!)
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate!
        annotationArray.append(annotation)
        mapView.addAnnotations(annotationArray)
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need persistence from launch to launch of your app or only in current launch? also you are missing some relevant parts of your code, your issue maybe is related to saving your array in firebase or maybe to your array of annotations initialization, can you provide all the relevant code?

Comment: In current launch. Added some more relevant pieces, but that's about it.

Comment: I think you need an array of locations and save that instead of only one location I think that is your main issue

Comment: Thank you Reinier. If I do create an array of locations, how would I then annotate them all?

Comment: what you mean with `how would I then annotate them all`? is the same method mapView.addAnnotations(annotationArray) you only have to make your annotationArray = YourLoadedCLLocationArrays from firebase

Comment: I'm thinking that won't work because the location array will not be of type [MKAnnotation], which is necessary for the addAnnotations method

Comment: You are right on that but you can always convert an array of CLLocationCoordinate2D into array of MKAnnotation

Comment: ^Wasn't able to implement this, but I understand what the issue is. I printed the coordinates of each member of the array in a label and discovered that the coordinates of each member are equal to the most recent location. But the annotationArray.count is increasing by 1 exactly as it should. So somehow, the newest annotation is overwriting each of the previous members of the array. Any ideas anyone??